# Passing a MutableArray between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
  BookingDocumentsViewController *bdVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookingDocs"];
    bdVc.orId = rl_id;
    bdVc.docsArray =  self.documentsArray;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:bdVc animated:YES];
```

I have Above code snippet. I'm trying to load a new viewcontroller and assign its Mutable Array (docsArray) object to current view's mutableArray (documentsArray <=this is not nil)

Whenever I execute above code I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

but if I comment the 3rd line. It works but I can't get my array to the new view. I even tried with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.documentsArray];` this doesnt work either.

But if I use `bdVc.docsArray =[[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` it works but again I can't get my mutable array to the new view.

Edit:
However 2nd line has NSString values. And they can be passed without a problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm not getting any errors in console, instead I get this.

[image]

Comment: Post the stacktrace of the crash.

Comment: Are you doing something with docsArray in bdVc's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear? Is docsArray a strong property?

Comment: yes docsArray is a strong property. And I'm not doing anything with docsArray in anywhere else.

Comment: As you've already been asked - Stack trace please.

Comment: No errors in console, app crashes.I updated the question.

Comment: @NikosM I just found that I'm doing a NSLOG with `docsArray.count` in bdVc's view didload. When I remove that it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue. A very basic mistake. In bdVc's viewDidLoad I had the following line,

`NSLog(@"Booking Documents viewDidLoad : %@",self.docsArray.count);`

This was causing the error. that %@ instead of %d. I wonder why xcode didn't show proper reason for the error.

Thank you all for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe consider using a Segue. It instantiates the destination viewcontroller for you. Then in your source view controller implement

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

Get a reference to your destination viewcontroller and set its data.

```
BookingDocumentsViewController *bdVc = [segue destinationViewController];
bdVc.docsArray = self.documentsArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

in BookingDocumentsViewController.h

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSmutableArray *docsArray;
```

You do can do in your BookingDocumentsViewController.m:

```
@synthesize docsArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    NSmutableArray *array = [NSmutableArray alloc]initWithArray:docsArray];   
   [super viewDidLoad];
 }
```

then when you are pushing the view

```
BookingDocumentsViewController *bdVc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BookingDocs"];
bdVc.orId = rl_id;
bdVc.docsArray =  self.documentsArray;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bdVc animated:YES];
[bdVc Release];
```

Comment: what is the point of creating a local array in viewDidLoad that isn't used anywhere? This is nowhere near an answer

Comment: well you can define that array in .h if you want to use it in other blocks i was just focusing on passing the array value funda...anyway will take care of that in future.